# Only replace if entire string is a match

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am using `gsub` to clean some character vectors, and some strings have not been entered completely, so I have e.g. a vector like this: `testvec<-c("alpha","alpha.town","alpha","alpha.town")`
I would like to convert it to this `c("alpha.town","alpha.town","alpha.town","alpha.town")`

I'm *sure* this question must already have an answer on StackOverflow but I can't find it. I have tried:
`gsub("alpha","alpha.town",testvec)`
`gsub("alpha","alpha.town",testvec,fixed=T)`
`gsub("\\balpha\\b","alpha.town",testvec,perl=T)`
`gsub("\\<alpha\\>","alpha.town",testvec)`

These all return `c("alpha.town","alpha.town.town","alpha.town","alpha.town.town")`

And `gsub(".*_alpha_.*","alpha.town",testvec)` just returns the original vector.

I'm obviously missing something! Maybe `gsub` is not even the right tool for this?
(it would be great to have a generalisable solution please and not just something like excluding cases with "alpha.")

Comment: Something like `gsub("^alpha$", "alpha.town", testvec)`

Comment: Try `gsub(".*alpha.*","alpha.town",testvec)`, no need for `_`

Comment: Both ```"^alpha$"``` and ```".*alpha.*"``` work :) - thanks!

Comment: In your case also `testvec[testvec == "alpha"] <- "alpha.town"` will work.